# "invalid label" parsererror with jQuery and Yahoo's Geolocation APIs

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp, yahoo

I'm using jQuery to access Yahoo's Geolocation APIs. Even though I am able to successfully retrieve data from their servers, I cannot get jQuery to successfully parse the data. I've tried both $.ajax() and $.getJSON, each returns the same failures: parsererror and "invalid label".

Through my digging on the interwebs, I've discovered that "invalid label" is likely the result of the JSON not being wrapped in parentheses, but I can't figure out how to wrap the data up, prior to it getting parsed. I'm not even convinced that's the problem.

Here's my code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var url  = "http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=39.0334171,-94.8320452&gflags=R&flags=JT&appid=supersecretappid&callback=?";

    $.getJSON(url, function() { alert("success"); })
      .error(function(data) { alert(JSON.stringify(data)); });

  });
```

The alternate version using just $.ajax is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: {},
  dataType: "jsonp",
  contentType: "text/plain",
  success: function(json) {
    alert("success");
  },
  error: function(x,y,z) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(x));
  }
});
```

Much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API you are trying to access doesn't support JSONP. So you cannot use it with javascript due to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restrictions. Try pasting the following url in your browser:

http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=39.0334171,-94.8320452&gflags=R&flags=JT&appid=supersecretappid&callback=foo

See how the `callback` parameter is completely ignored? The server returns pure JSON, not JSONP which is what you need. As a workaround you could write a server side script on your domain that will act as a bridge between Yahoo and your domain. Then you will send the AJAX request to your script.

Comment: I was trying to push the callback and parsing to the client in order to free up server resources. Guess I have to hahve the server handle it.